# Como colocar um input submit dentro do input text?

Tags: html, css

Tenho esse HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="pesquisa" placeholder="O que você procura?"/>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

E tenho esse CSS:

```
body>header form{
    margin:25px 80px;
    display:inline-block;
}

body>header form input[type=text]{
    padding:8px 50px 8px 20px;
    width:300px;
    font-family:'Open Sans';
    font-size:13px;
    border-top:1px solid #C21B13 !important;
    border:3px solid #C21B13;
    border-radius:20px;
    outline:none;
}

body>header form input[type=submit]{ }
```

O meu site ta assim:

[image: site]

**O que eu quero fazer?**
Eu quero colocar esse botão enviar dentro do input.

Como faço isso de maneira correta?

ATT.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Na verdade o botão não é colocado dentro do `<input>`.

Uma solução é basicamente deixar seu `input[type="text"]` sem borda e envolver o `<form>` com um elemento que causará a impressão de que o submit está dentro. A ideia seria:

<kbd>[image: snippet-example]</kbd>

```css
form {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
}

form > input {
  border: none
}

form > button {
  background: royalblue;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 4px 10px
}
```

```html
<form action='/' method='post'>
  <input type='text' name='pesquisa' placeholder='O que você procura?'>
  <button type='submit'>Pesquisar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: É porque no caso eu queria estilizar o input quando ele estiver focado (:focus) no caso mudando a cor da borda, mas fazendo assim fica só a parte do meio com a borda, será que tem outra forma de colocar o botão dentro do input?

Comment: Ja consegui aranjar a solução... position:absolute; margin:-20px 240px; Mas me serviu pra outra coisa sua resposta :)

Answer (score 3):

O botão não está dentro do input:

```css
.box {
    border:1px solid #444;
    width:300px;
}

.box input {
    display:inline-block;
    outline:0;
    border:0;
    padding: 5px;
}

.box .button {
    background: #aaa;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    border:none;
    float:right;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Pesquisar..." />
    <button type="submit" class="button">Pesquisar</button>
</div>
```