# Como colocar 2 inputs lado a lado?

Tags: html, css, input

Como posso colocar 2 `input` alinhados lado a lado?

[image: elemento]

```
<li>
<input type="text" /><input type="checkbox" />
</li>
```

Comment: A lógica é a mesma [dessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43490/como-colocar-um-input-submit-dentro-do-input-text/43496#43496).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É bem simples, o CSS tem isso:

```css
.campo1 {
   float:left;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="campo1" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/LeftInput.js).